# ElasticSearch - Fuzzy search in list elements

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got some documents stored in ElasticSearch like this:
    `{
        "tag" : ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
        ...
 }`

I want to search through the "tag" field. I know that It should work with a query like:
    `{
        "query":
        {
            "match" : {"tag" : "tag1"}
        }
 }`

But, I don't want to use a match, I want to use a fuzzy search through the list, for example, something like:
     `{
        "query":
        {
            "fuzzy" : {"tag" : "tagg1"}
        }
}`
The problem is, the above query doesn't return anything. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of tag field in your elasticsearch mapping ?

I have tried with following type for tag field & elastisearch version is 7.2

`"tag" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }`

And working well for me.

Query With elastic fuzzy will be :

```
{
  "query":
    {
        "fuzzy": {"tag" : "tagg1"}
    }
 }
```

Comment: It's a list of strings. Did you use the same type?

Comment: Yes It's same a list with document source like "_source" : {
          "tag" : [
            "tag1",
            "tag2",
            "tag3"
          ]
        }

Comment: I don't know why mine doesn't work:( Maybe it's because I use version 6.5.4.

Comment: What is the type of tag field as per your index mapping?

Comment: I have try something like this 
POST newdata/new
{
  "tag" : ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
  
}

GET newdata/new/_search
{
  "query":
        {
            "fuzzy": {"tag" : "tagg1"}
        }
}